# The option to change site language isn't available

Tags: language

I have a Wordpress installation that's set to English by default, but I want to change it to Polish. From what I found, there's supposed to be an option in Settings -> General, right below "Week Starts On", but there's nothing there. How can I change the site's language? I don't want a multi-language site or anything complex like that, I just want to fully switch to Polish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its because of your low network bandwidth and if you wait in general tab or connect to better network, it will appear there.
The reason is this part (new languages) needs to be downloaded from network.

Comment: Thanks! I know what's wrong now. The server is currently having problems with outgoing network connections (proxy problems), so if the language changer needs network, it makes sense that it doesn't work at the moment.